# Vector Countdown

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a homework problem that I'm stuck on. My code is supposed to resize a vector, then countdown from that specific vector's size. I'm just not sure how I'm supposed to populate the vector to count down from any number.
ex: if `newSize` is 3, the output would be 3 2 1

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<int> countDown(0);
   int newSize = 0;
   int i = 0;

   newSize = 3;

   //Student code start

   countDown.resize(newSize);  

   //Student code end

   for (i = 0; i < newSize; ++i) {
      cout << countDown.at(i) << " ";
   }
   cout << "Go!" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do u need to resize manually? vector resizes automatically, all you need to do is add more elements

Comment: it would have taken you less time to just search for "add int to vector" than to write this whole question.

Answer (score 1):

Time to bust out our favorite [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) where we find [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) which does what we need:

```
// 1. Resize
countDown.resize(newSize);
// 2. Fill with sequence, traversing backwards (thus rbegin and rend)
std::iota(countDown.rbegin(), countDown.rend(), 1);
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce17b4f5dd9c0875)

Comment: yeah i think his professor will definitely know he cheated with this answer.

Comment: @TritonMan Thinking about it, you are probably right. But I'd rather not post a superfluous loop as an answer, hopefully someone learns something from this, like using a reference and standard algorithms. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, resize (looks like you got that part:

countDown.resize(newSize);

Then do your for loop - you're looking for it to iterate as much as new size but to count down rather than up. So you can't just make it = i and you can't make it = newSize as another solution suggested (newSize doesn't change as loops progress). So, we just take newSize and subtract i from it to make a countdown. Thus:

```
for (i = 0; i < newSize; ++i){
countDown.at(i) = newSize-i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is tasking you to resize the vector countDown and to populate countDown with integers that start from the value of newSize to 1.

The OP has already provided how to complete the first task in using the following:

```
countDown.resize(newSize);
```

For the next task you must find a way to assign the first index of countDown with the value newSize, the second index with the value newSize - 1, etc. until you reach 1.

Because your homework shows you are outputting the elements of countDown from first  element to the last index with the following for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < countDown.size(); ++i) {
      cout << countDown.at(i) << " ";
   }
```

It would be practical for your for loop that will assign values to the elements in countDown to follow the same format as when you output them:

```
for (i = 0; i < countDown.size(); ++i) {}
```

Using this format means i will be 0 in the first iteration, 1 in the 2nd iteration, and will continue to increment until i is equal to countDown.size(), in which the loop will no longer iterate. You can use this to your advantage with the following statement within the for loop:

```
countDown.at(i) = newSize - i;
```

The first iteration of this statement would translate to: countDown.at(0) = newSize - 0. The second iteration would then be: countDown.at(1) = newSize - 1. This would continue until the last element in countDown is assigned with 1, which completes the 2nd task of the lab.

There are great alternative approaches to completing this, but I found this solution best with what you will have learned so far up to this point along with its simplicity. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) the elements one by one:

```
//Student code start

for (i = 0; i < newSize; ++i) {
    countDown.push_back(newSize - i);
}  

//Student code end
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/WXMM20918)

Note that [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) will only append elements with default value of int (i.e. `0`) in your case.

Comment: @Downvoter, it would be nice to leave a comment telling us what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<int> countDown(0);
   int newSize = 0;
   int i = 0;

   newSize = 3;

  countDown.resize(newSize);
 for (i = 0; i < newSize; ++i){
  countDown.at(i) = newSize-i;
}

   for (i = 0; i < newSize; ++i) {
      cout << countDown.at(i) << " ";
   }
   cout << "Go!" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess that, with each new iteration (i) you should print (cout) newsize-(i+1)....

So, at the first iteration will print the newsize minus 1, then print newsize minus 2, then 3, all without changing the original newsize value.

Comment: well, actually it does't need to rest (i+1), just i itself, so the printing will begin with 3, then 2, then 1.